# Sharing Google Play link on facebook and wrong thumbnail

Tags: android, facebook

When I tried to publish a link on my android facebook app, the thumbnail is wrong. It is random image from the site. I have:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "my google play link");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share with"));
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 5):

You can't fix that, Google's play store does not have [og metadata tags](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/) on their webpages to specify which image to use when shared on Facebook.  As a consequence, Facebook will then just pick one to show in the composer and there isn't much you can do to change that.

Answer (score 0):

Use this debugger from Facebook to manage image to be shown : https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing

Delete all images from Google Play. Then add image you want to be displayed, including "Tablets". Then use "Scrap Again" in FB debugger.

It's a bit random, but with some experiments you can get what you want.